# Windows disable enhancedpowermanagement by default

Tags: usb, windows-registry, hid

I use many USB HID devices and since Windows 8, the Power Management disables them by default.

I wrote a script to change that, but I don't want to have to run this script every time I add a device.

```
@echo off
setlocal
set key=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\USB\VID_XXXX^&PID_XXXX
for /f %%a in ('reg query "%key%"') do (
   reg add "%key%\%%~na\Device Parameters" /t REG_DWORD /f /v EnhancedPowerManagementEnabled /d 0x0 
)
```

Is there a way to set the registry key of *enhancedpowermanagement* to 0 by default ?
Using a custom INF for a HID device ?

Comment: Still hunting for a way to do it ...